# Laurent series on different areas?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Looking for the Laurent series of

$f(z)=\frac{1}{z(z-1)(3i-z)}=\frac{i}{3 z} + \frac{\frac{1}{10} - \frac{i}{30}}{z - 3 i} - \frac{\frac{1}{10} + \frac{3i}{10}}{z - 1}$

So we look for $z_0=0,z_1=1,z_2=3i$ on

$A=\{z \in \Bbb C: |z| <1\}$

$B=\{z \in \Bbb C: 1< |z| <3\}$

$C=\{z \in \Bbb C: 3< |z| < \infty\}$

On $A$:

$\frac{i}{3 z}=\frac{i}{3 (z-1+1)}=\frac{i}{3 }\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{i}{3 }(z-1)^n(-1)^n $

$\frac{\frac{1}{10} - \frac{i}{30}}{z - 3 i} =\frac{1}{z}\frac{\frac{1}{10} - \frac{i}{30}}{1 - 3 i/z}=\frac{1}{z }\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{1}{10} - \frac{i}{30})(-\frac{3i}{z })^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{1}{10} - \frac{i}{30})((-\frac{3i}{z })^{n+1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{10} - \frac{i}{30})((-\frac{3i}{z })^n$

$\frac{\frac{1+3i}{10}}{z - 1}=-\frac{1+3i}{10}\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n $

Is this correct and how is this different to B and C ? How would I begin with in B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: for $|z|<1$ we have $$\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$$  but for $|z|>1$ we have $$\frac{1}{1-z} =-\frac{1}{z} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z}} = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{z^n}$$